# How do I POST with jQuery/Ajax in Django?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, post

I am trying to POST data using jQuery/AJAX in Django and am having trouble.  When I run the code below and click on the 'test' button, the entire page re-loads again, which isn't what I want to happen (that's why I'm using AJAX).

I'm also not able to confirm the AJAX request is getting to the Django view.

**EDIT:** I've made the edits for return false and `event.preventDefault()`.  A new page doesn't load, but I'm still not able to see the updated text in the `<div id='message'>` field. I'm not sure if the data is getting sent. I'm seeing in the console:

```
POST /edit_favorites/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2294
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def edit_favorites(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Not Ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^edit_favorites/', 'edit_favorites'),
```

**HTML**:

```html
<form method='post' id='test'>
  <input type="hidden" value="video34"/>
  <input type='submit' value='Test button'/>
  <div id='message'>Initial text</div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#test").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/edit_favorites/",
      data: {
        'video': $('#test').val() // from form
      },
      success: function () {
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Any advice?

Comment: Breakpoint in the view; is the view code running? Breakpoint in the ajax success handler; is it running? Add ajax error handler; put breakpoint there; is it running? Also, 2 random side notes: you can use `$('#test').serializeArray()`, and it is recommended you capture only the url you mean to: `url(r'^edit_favorites/$', ...` (without the $ you capture any url beginning with that).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Misplaced `return false;`. It should be at the end of `.submit()` function. So move it one line upwards:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#test").submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/edit_favorites/",
      data: {
        'video': $('#test').val() // from form
      },
      success: function () {
        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
      }
    });
    return false; //<---- move it here
  });

});
```

**UPDATE:**

About the issue `POST /edit_favorites/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2294`. Check on this post which looks similar to your issue:

- [Django jQuery post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744159/django-jquery-post-request)

Comment: I've made the edits for return false and event.preventDefault(). A new page doesn't load, but I'm still not able to see the updated text in the div id = 'message' field. I'm not sure if the data is getting sent.

Comment: @sharataka Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744159/django-jquery-post-request

Comment: I believe it is because that's what I have in the urlconf.

Comment: Looks like, you need to include a CSRF (cross-site request forgery) token in your ajax call.

Comment: @MuthuKumaran - I understand that it is possible to send ajax `POST` request to a **different view** than the one used to render the form **initially**. To that end, I have tried function view to post form data (*serialized*) but somehow the data is not posted to the DB. I can see the form data serialized in the *console* but unable to `POST` it to the DB. Is it possible for you to point to a *minimal* example of just doing what I am trying to acheive?

Answer (score 6):

the following methods worked to me. and i hope help you too.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def edit_favorites(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "Yes, AJAX!"
    else:
        message = "Not Ajax"
    return HttpResponse(message)
```

Comment: Are there any requirements for JsonResponse isted of HttpResponse

Answer (score 4):

What is going on here is when you submit an HTML form, it sends the form's data to the `action` attribute of the `<form>`. In your javascript you subscribe to the submit event of the form, however you never disable the default behavior of the form, which is to follow the `action` attribute. In jQuery, you can modify that behavior by calling `preventDefault` method on the event argument, and returning `false` (if you call `preventDefault`, then returning `false` is not necessary but its better to make sure...):

```
$(...).submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT**

As for the error, your error is not very helpful but I have a hunch that you do not validate CSRF. More and detailed explanation of that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/). Quick fix however is just to include [this](https://gist.github.com/3892061) file in addition to your jQuery and add [`ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator to your view.

Comment: I've made the edits for return false and event.preventDefault(). A new page doesn't load, but I'm still not able to see the updated text in the div id = 'message' field. I'm not sure if the data is getting sent.

Comment: Does the text update to `<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>`? In firebug do you get any errors?

Comment: I'm not using firebug, but I see "POST /edit_favorites/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2294 in the console...does this help troubleshoot?

Comment: Not really but I have a hunch about CSRF. Check the edit in the answer.