# How to filter a ModelMultipleChoiceField based on another field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Based on the form below, I would like to know If Is there a way (or a plugin) to use the field tipo_indicador to filter indicadores field:

```
tipo_indicador = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=TipoIndicador.objects.all(),
    label=u'Tipo de indicador',
    required=False,
)

indicadores = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
    label= _(u'Indicadores'),
    required=False,
    queryset=Indicador.objects.all(),
    widget=admin_widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(verbose_name=_(u'indicadores'), is_stacked=False)
)
```

Comment: You have to use `ajax`.

Comment: on change value get data from ajax call.

Comment: @albar do you have an example?

Comment: I've found this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43939201/dynamically-update-django-form-field-options-using-ajax-to-get-new-queryset I'll try.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Please look into these django plugins - https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects.   https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/.   Specific  content - https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#filtering-results-based-on-the-value-of-other-fields-in-the-form