# Can i pass information between Django and HTML in same request for user?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am creating certain model's object picker which is activated when user sends a post request via HTML forms. More specifically once user clicks certain submit button and post request is sent to the website, It then returns variable which is then used by javascript to open a status window.

Here is all the code associated with these actions:

**HTML**

```
<form id="item_selection1" action="{% url 'Home:AccountPage' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input class="sendtrade" name="sendtrade1" type="submit" value="Send Offer">
</form>
```

**Python - views.py** (3 dots represent all unassociated code)

```
...
prepareTrade1 = "false"
...
if request.POST.get('sendtrade1'):
    prepareTrade1 = "true"
    ...
return render(request, 'Home/name.html', {"...": "...", 'prepareTrade1': prepareTrade1})
```

**Javascript in HTML**

```
if ( "{{ prepareTrade1 }}" == "true" ) {
    $(".process_overlay").css("display", "block")
}
```

Shortly, when user clicks the submit button box appears, What i'm trying to do, Is to display status of object query.

So for example, If i received ObjectDoesNotExist error from `test.py` which belongs in the same directory as `views.py`, How could i direct that information to HTML/Javascript user is receiving? If creation of absolute new request is required, Then still, How could i do that? Am i required to use Ajax requests?

So in short, Asynchronously when template `name.html` is rendered, The script `name.py` which belongs in the same directory as `views.py` should be executed, And lets take the example that ObjectDoesNotExist exception will be raised in `name.py` How could i pass it to template? I think the process is called XHR.

Comment: Are you using Ajax requests or you are renderings the template and js in it

Comment: @ArpitSolanki No i am just rendering templates as seen in the code, Are ajax requests necessary in this case?

Comment: Just remove the quotes from "{{ prepareTrade1 }}" and you are good. It would work.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki The following code is fully functional, Even in quotes, What i'm trying to do is make live action template rendering, So for example, Once template `name.html` is visible to user, Script `test.py` is executed and it should direct it's status as variable to `name.html` to that user, Could that be possible?

Comment: Use Ajax requests in js and send a json response from your Django view

Comment: @ArpitSolanki Thanks for the answer, Could you give more information like how could i do this with ajax requests? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ajax requests to update variables from server.

Here goes you form

```html
<form id="item_selection1" action="{% url 'Home:AccountPage' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="sendtrade" name="sendtrade1" type="submit" value="Send Offer">
</form>
```

You should rewrite you view to support ajax requests:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def your_view(request):    
    ...
    prepareTrade1 = "false"
    ...
    if request.POST.get('sendtrade1'):
        prepareTrade1 = "true"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'prepareTrade1': prepareTrade1}))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'prepareTrade1': 'false'}))
```

And add following javascript:

```js
$(function() {
  var form = $('#item_selection1');

  $(form).submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(form).serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: $(form).attr('action'),
      data: formData,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.prepareTrade1 == "true") {
          $(".process_overlay").css("display", "block");
        }
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the answer, But for example i have script `name.py`, which will be executed when button is clicked, And for example i get exception from the script and request is already loaded, How can i update that request with following exception?

Comment: Do you want to pass exception message to client-side? This way you should simply pass two variables in json-response: status and message. And depends on status success function will either show block or exception message.

Comment: But for example, If i executed script from different process, Could i pass exception message to client side? For example i wanted to use time.sleep function on script which would give exception result.

Comment: You mean that it's called another view on button click, not that renderes a template? Or you call the same view on button click, but in this view another function is called?

Comment: I mean when button is clicked, same view is called, But yes, in this view another function is called which must always work and if it gets updated it must send information to rendered HTML. So HTML must be rendered along with script, Even if script is not yet finished. I think it is called XHR.

Comment: In this way, you can do two things. First, in you view you could call the function with parallel execution and set limit for time waiting, and returns answer depends on the fact did the function end (success message) or not (exception message). You can also set timeout limit to ajax function without changing you server-side architecture. This way ajax must have two callbacks for success and error. Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes, Couldn't this also be done without Ajax? For example if i created another thread for script and rendered HTML, Then transferred information with websockets?

Comment: If you don't use ajax, you page will be reloaded each time. Using ajax is the most simple way to achive what you want. You can do parallel execution on server-side to get exception message but you shouldn't transfer information in any other way. That's very unsafe.

Comment: You could also use interecooler lib which make ajax quite simple. Look [this example](https://www.petercuret.com/add-ajax-to-django-without-writing-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! My question was fully answered now, I will just learn more about Ajax and use it for good.

Answer (score 1):

Make a separate function to check for the value prepareTrade1 and this function will be used by your frontend side to show the window. csrf exempt is used just for simplicity of example

```
@csrf_exempt 
def check_trade(request):
    if request.POST.get('sendtrade1'):
        prepareTrade1 = "true"
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"prepareTrade": "true"}))
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"prepareTrade": "false"}))
```

Now the ajax request using jquery

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: URL,
        data: {"sendtrade1": "somevalue"},
        success: function (response) {
          response = JSON.parse(response)
          // now time for the logic you mentioned
          if ( response.prepareTrade == "true" ) {
               $(".process_overlay").css("display", "block")
          }
        }
    });
```

Some links that might help you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465764/5250746

[Ajax tutorial for post and get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9436534/ajax-tutorial-for-post-and-get)

Comment: So i should just add my script to views.py as a request function? And then how could i send this data to other request which shows the user information?

Comment: The jQuery code will go to your script tag in your html template and check_trade function will go to views.py

Comment: Sorry i'm not experienced in Ajax so i don't quite understand, So if i use this code, If user submits the button both request function and my script should be executed right? And then if i receive ObjectDoesNotExist exception how could i show it on request view?

Comment: The example only explains how to make Ajax requests. If you want to attach a handler like listener to button click or submit button then you can use $('#idofsubmitbutton').on('click', function ()).  Then write your Ajax logic in the function provided in the callback

Comment: Also see the other answer for more clarifications

Comment: Yes, But once script is executed (and script doesn't belong in views.py), How can i pass variables between it and ajax request?

Comment: Your js is always available in the html file and it will be executed everytime someone submits the form(the other answer) and views code will be executed everytime you make the Ajax request

Comment: Yes but also asynchronously with request being rendered, script called `name.py` should be executed, And can i use ajax request inside that `name.py` script ?

Comment: There is one simple concept. There is your server running where your views will receive requests. Ajax request will make request to the URL and Django will return the response. That's all other than that nothing is related between your js and Django. Also you can't use a js code inside name.py.

Comment: So i still couldn't pass variables between `name.py` and `name.html` template in a "live action"? Apologies, I'm not quite sure what is this process called.

Comment: I am sorry to say this but you are really having hard time grasping this concept. You have to read about js Ajax and how client server works.

Comment: The concept itself seems quite difficult, But may i ask if this could be done with ajax? Passing variables between `name.py` and `name.html` in a live action? I'm not even sure if this can be done at all...