# POST object in form directly

Tags: html, django

Is it possible to save an object through Django HTML form with the value in option tag directly?

```
<select class="form-control" name="person">
        <option selected disabled>Choose</option>
        {% for person in group %}
        <option value="{{ person }}">{{ person.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name
```

Tried the above but I get "didn't return a HttpResponse object". I know I can pass an ID but is it possible to save the object directly instead of going to views.py and getting the object via an ID?

Comment: Solved:


`person = Person.objects.get(pk=request.POST['person'])`

I guess I CAN send objects through form, just the way I was going about in views.py was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using AJAX request, but you still need a view(URL) that creates the object

Hint: [How do I POST with jQuery/Ajax in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465711/how-do-i-post-with-jquery-ajax-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

You can save the object using the value in option tag which is the person name, by fetching the object using the person_name value as below:

Assuming the value you are getting from the option tag as person_name and the object you are trying to save is Group object.

```
Group.objects.get(person__name=person_name)
```

and then update the object.

Comment: But won't I need another column in my Model just to store the "name"?

Comment: @jayimshan I assume your Person model would have a column name right. person__name would refer to the column name in Person model.