# how to pass a JavaScript variable to Django views

Tags: javascript, django

I'm new to Django and HTML.
i have a code like below:

```
...
<script>
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
</script>
...
```

I need to pass the var `(["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"])` to my Django view.

Comment: I think you should make your question clearer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), send the data via POST and then in the Django view you can access it with `request.POST`.

You can use this as a reference:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html
[How do I POST with jQuery/Ajax in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465711/how-do-i-post-with-jquery-ajax-in-django)

Comment: can u see my new question?