# How to get data from form and show in dropdown in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

**What I m trying to do:**

Upload a CSV file(Form #1) and show header of a CSV file in the dropdown (Form #2). 
and these forms are on the same page.

**What I have tried:**

for now I able to upload CSV file and display header in a webpage.

**index.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="file1">Upload Files</label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" accept=".csv" id="file1" name="file"  required="True" class="form-control custom-file-input">
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="file1"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn text-white w-50" value="Upload">Upload</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def read_csv(request):
    csv_file = request.FILES['file']
    data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    i = list(data.head(0))
    context = {'loaded_data': i}
    return render(request, "WebApp/index.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX request to handle this. You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13465764/2474573), which has a sample AJAX request. In the `views.py` file, you can handle the request by checking `request.is_ajax()` and return the context you produce from CSV file via `JsonResponse`. At the success part of the AJAX call, you can manipulate the dropdown DOM element. There is a good tutorial [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html). If you are not familiar with these, feel free to ask about the parts you are confused.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already looked into that but the answer was simple.

Answer (score 0):

So data was in a list I just have to loop through `<option>`:

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
   {% for x in loaded_data %}
      <option value="{{ x }}">
             {{ x }}
      </option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```